# Extracting row from matrix 2 using index from matrix 1

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, numpy, sparse-matrix

I have two matrices, one of texts and one of word frequencies in the text. I remove one row from word frequency matrix. How can I then extract a row from the word frequency matrix, using the text number (row index from the text matrix)?

For example:

**Step 1: List of texts**

I have a list of texts in rows, where each text is referred to by its row number:

```
>>print type(texts)
>>print texts.shape
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
(53,)
```

**Step 2: Select texts based on their row number**

And I have a range like this:

```
>>print train_range
>>[ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
  26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50
  51 52]
```

This range is used to select rows from `texts`. This basically means deleting one text, as only 52 row indices in the `train_range`. In the below example, the first row (row 0) is removed, as 0 is not in `train_range`:

```
texts[train_range]
```

**Step 3: Get word frequencies of texts**

The texts are then analysed (by word frequency) to return a sparse matrix `train_X`. Since each text is a row in `texts`, the word frequencies for each text are placed in a row in `train_X`. So `texts` has 53 rows, `texts[train_range]` has 52 rows, and `train_X` has 52 rows:

```
trainX = get_word_freq_matrix( texts[train_range] )
>>print train_X.shape
(52, 6237)
>>print type(train_X)
<class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'>
```

**Step 4: Get word frequencies for some texts**

I now want to get rows from `train_X` with their original text number, using a new range, like this:

```
apply_range = [4,7,8]
train_X[apply_range]
```

However, the numbers in `apply_range` (like `train_range`) refer to the rows in `texts`. The numbers don't refer to the rows in `train_X`. How can I use this range to get the correct frequencies from `train_X` based on where they appear in `texts`?

I have tried [referencing rows in a matrix using index from another matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12317151/referencing-rows-in-a-matrix-using-index-from-another-matrix). However, I'm not sure how this can work, as the function doesn't take into account WHICH text was deleted from `texts`.

Comment: You'll probably have to save somewhere some information about which rows were deleted and then get the correct indexes to be used for `train_X` using a function. Something like `train_X[get_correct_indexes([4,7,8], who_got_deleted)]`.
At least this shouldn't be too hard to implement, maybe there are better ways of doing this.

Comment: From a cursory look, it seems that you're associating different types of data together. Rather than storing them in separate parallel lists (where the association is based in position in the list), perhaps a dictionary datatype of key/value pairs might better serve your needs?

Answer (score 1):

With everything else like you explained in the question, just do

```
apply_range = [4,7,8]
train_X[[train_range.index(i) for i in apply_range]]
```